# Reusing passwords from ~/.couchapp.conf for different applications' .couchapprc

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

The manual at http://couchapp.org/page/couchapp-config says that you can store passwords in `~/.couchapp.conf`. However, the `db` url is acutally the url to the specific database. If there are two applications in different databases, say `/db1` and `/db2`, then we'd have to have this:

```
{
  "env" : {
    "default" : {
      "db" : "http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db1"
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
{
  "env" : {
    "default" : {
      "db" : "http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db2"
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't see how this can be merged into one (unless instead of `default` a hack is used to add one "environment" per DB, e.g. `default-db1` and `default-db2` and such).

How can I combine this into one, so e.g. I specify `db1` and `db2` within `.couchapprc` files in respective applications or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in `dist-packages/couchapp/config.py`, method `Config.load` does this in the middle:

```
new_conf = util.read_json(p, use_environment=True,
    raise_on_error=True)
```

Note `use_environment=True`. This is not a perfect thing, as it does not take into account the variables within global ~/.couchapp.conf file, but it gives at least a workaround - just define the necessary environment variables, say `COUCHAPP_USER` and `COUCHAPP_PASS`, and use them in the .couchapprc file:

```
"db" : "http://$COUCHAPP_USER:$COUCHAPP_PASS@localhost:5984/db1"
```

Now you can run `couchapp push`:

```
$ export COUCHAPP_USER=testadmin 
$ export COUCHAPP_PASS=pass 
$ couchapp push
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now, but I think you should simply merge the two environments giving them different names (e.g. "env1", and "env2"):

```
{
  "env" : {
    "env1" : {
      "db" : "http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db1"
    },
    "env2" : {
      "db" : "http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/db2"
    }
  }
}
```

Then pass the environment as the last command line argument: `couchapp push env1`.

However I think the easiest solution is to put the info in `.couchapprc` in the root of the project, then add it to `.gitignore`, `.htignore`, or whatever you use for version control.

Comment: The issue is that I want to have this separate. I don't want to define all the environments in the global file, I don't want to spread passwords all around (e.g. if I change the pass, I'd have to change everywhere) and, when shared, it's important to have others use their settings instead of mine.